# replace numbers between specific characters using jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to replace digits that are exactly next to a-z A-Z 0-9 .-_ linebreak space and they are exactly before a-z A-Z 0-9 .-
but not those between 2 spaces or 2 other language characters.

I have strings like :

```
 1. "www.asdf123asd.com"
 2. "asd123.sdf"
 3. "123.sdf"
 4. "adf 123 asdf"
```

and I want to change them to :

```
 1. "www.asdf<b>123</b>asd.com"
 2. "asd<b>123</b>.sdf"
 3. "<b>123</b>.sdf"
 4. "adf 123 asdf"
```

any suggestion?

Comment: http://www.regex101.com - have a play with it, sounds like you've got the matching sorted already

Comment: this is a sample, I have thousands of rows in tables and I have to do this for all.

Comment: Yep. Try this for a starting point: http://regex101.com/r/dH8jV1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
repl = string.replace(/(^|[a-z_.-])(\d+)(?=[a-z_.-])/ig, "$1<b>$2</b>");
```

**TESTS:**

```
> "www.asdf123.com".replace(/(^|[a-z_.-])(\d+)(?=[a-z_.-])/ig, "$1<b>$2</b>");
"www.asdf<b>123</b>.com"

> "www.asdf 123 asd.com".replace(/(^|[a-z_.-])(\d+)(?=[a-z_.-])/ig, "$1<b>$2</b>");
"www.asdf 123 asd.com"

> "123.sdf".replace(/(^|[\w.-])(\d+)(?=[\w.-])/g, "$1<b>$2</b>");
"<b>123</b>.sdf"
```